# Is it possible to start an FTP session via bash?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer, bash, ftp

Is it possible to start a session with an Android Samsung Galaxy smartphone through a bash shell to access files remotely?

Comment: Are you asking about starting an ftp client or server? on the phone or on a remote system?

Comment: You can also consider using SSH for opening a remote shell session and for file transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Search for SwiFTP or FTPServer in the market. They turn your phone into an FTP server and will let you connect using the client of your choice, which would include the bash ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wifi File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-file-explorer/com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorer) and I've found it works great.

Comment: Nice for you -- but how does that relate to the question?